# remove mail send client ssmtp and lsb-invalid-mta

Tags: sendmail

I had `ssmtp` installed on my local desktop, due to some testing.

now I uninstalled it with apt-get remove and in automatcally installed `lsb-invalid-mta`

If I try to uninstall that too, it will install `postfix`.

how do i remove all mail programs at all?

or are they removed now?

(`lsb-invalid-mta` is a dummy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of `lsb-invalid-mta`:

> This package contains nothing else than a fake /usr/sbin/sendmail
>   command to fulfill the LSB's requirement of providing this command without
>   requiring an MTA to get installed, which once introduces a daemon which
>   can cause security problems and second, users get asked questions about
>   how they want their MTA configured when in reality they simply wanted to
>   install a deskltop application or a printer driver, but the dependency on
>   LSB compliance pulls in an MTA with the installation.

So why not just leave `lsb-invalid-mta` installed?